# extract multiple string pattern and return to a single value in r

Tags: r, string

I have a string:

```
test<-c("Compound.name:Cyclohexylamine;CAS.ID:108-91-8;HMDB.ID:HMDB31404;KEGG.ID:C00571;Lab.ID:shen_4881_HMDB31404;Adduct:(M+H)+;mz.error:0.5703867;mz.match.score:0.9997398;RT.error:NA;RT.match.score:NA;CE:Unknown_1;SS:0.52575;Total.score:0.7034962;Database:hmdbDatabase0.0.1
120 Levels: Compound.name:3-Dehydroxycarnitine;CAS.ID:;HMDB.ID:HMDB06831;KEGG.ID:C05543\t;Lab.ID:shen_3269_HMDB06831;Adduct:(M+H)+;mz.error:0.7554105;mz.match.score:0.9995436;RT.error:NA;RT.match.score:NA;CE:Unknown_1;SS:0.6706675;Total.score:0.793996;Database:hmdbDatabase0.0.1"
```

I used str_extract to extract multiple patterns from the string:

```
str_extract(test,pattern = c("Compound\\.name(.*?);","HMDB\\.ID(.*?);","KEGG\\.ID(.*?);","mz\\.match\\.score(.*?);"))

[1] "Compound.name:Cyclohexylamine;" "HMDB.ID:HMDB31404;"             "KEGG.ID:C00571;"               
[4] "mz.match.score:0.9997398;"
```

I would like the result to return to a single value, how to do that?
like:

```
[1] "Compound.name:Cyclohexylamine;HMDB.ID:HMDB31404;KEGG.ID:C00571;mz.match.score:0.9997398;"
```

Comment: try `paste(..., collapse="")` on result of `str_extract`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `paste` the string together with empty `collapse` argument.

```
library(stringr)
paste0(str_extract(test, pattern = c("Compound\\.name(.*?);","HMDB\\.ID(.*?);",
       "KEGG\\.ID(.*?);","mz\\.match\\.score(.*?);")), collapse = "")

#[1]Compound.name:Cyclohexylamine;HMDB.ID:HMDB31404;KEGG.ID:C00571;mz.match.score:0.9997398;"
```

Or since you are already using `stringr`, you can also use `str_c` instead of `paste0`.

---

We can use it as a function

```
apply_fun <- function(x) {
    paste0(str_extract(test, pattern = c("Compound\\.name(.*?);","HMDB\\.ID(.*?);",
           "KEGG\\.ID(.*?);","mz\\.match\\.score(.*?);")), collapse = "")
}
```

and then apply for each value in the column using `sapply`

```
sapply(df$column_name, apply_fun)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ronak Shah. I tried to use this as a function:
function(x)paste0(str_extract(x, pattern = c("Compound\\.name(.*?);","HMDB\\.ID(.*?);",
       "KEGG\\.ID(.*?);","mz\\.match\\.score(.*?);")), collapse = "")
and I apply to a datafrme where the values are similar to my example, but I get error:
Warning message:
In stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing.
May I know why?

Comment: @LennonLee You need to use `sapply` to apply it for every value in the column. check updated answer.